# Tezos RPC shows baker as one of the delegated contracts

Tags: node, rpc, baker, delegating, tezos-reward-distributor

When querying the tezos rpc, the baker address is shown under the `delegated_contracts`, this causes an issue when using tezos-reward-distributor to payout the rewards since TRD looks at the rpc and creates a payment transaction to pay the baker.

What seems to be the configuration issue that causes the baker to be listed as a delegated_contract? I have pretty much followed the default baker node setup, the only change was to use a `remote-signer`

Ref : https://testnet-tezos.giganode.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/delegates/tz1PgkWZdr5Vcbb3CbhubheYuEGpxJtKDMhT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The baker address showing under `delegated_contracts` has been introduced in Babylon protocol upgrade. This behavior will be restored to the formed state, which doesn't include the baker address, in an up-coming proposal.

In the meantime, I think you can setup a rule in tezos-reward-distributor to keep the baker's payment in the baking address: [see the `rules_map` parameter with `TOB` value](https://tezos-reward-distributor-organization.github.io/tezos-reward-distributor/configuration.html#baker-configuration).